# Background color does not change it when sidebar is collapsed

Tags: css, reactjs, sidebar

I am working on a sidebar project which uses react-pro-sidebar. The sidebar has 2 modes, expanded and collapsed. When collapsed, only the icons are available. If I click on a menu item the active element will change its background to colors.greenAccent[500] and remain like this until another element is clicked. The problem I currently have is that if I collapsed the sidebar and change to a different menu item the background color will not change. I have tried creating conditions so it is collapsed it also changes the background code, but none of them have worked. I think there might be some CSS property overwriting that condition but I am not sure.

This is the code:

```
import { Sidebar, Menu, MenuItem, useProSidebar } from 'react-pro-sidebar';
import { useState } from "react";
import { tokens } from "../theme";
import { Box, IconButton, Typography, useTheme } from "@mui/material";
import { Link, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import DashboardRoundedIcon from '@mui/icons-material/DashboardRounded';
import TwitterIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Twitter';
import SportsSoccerIcon from '@mui/icons-material/SportsSoccer';
import EditNotificationsIcon from '@mui/icons-material/EditNotifications';
import PeopleIcon from '@mui/icons-material/People';
import CalendarMonthIcon from '@mui/icons-material/CalendarMonth';
import TimelineIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Timeline';
import BarChartIcon from '@mui/icons-material/BarChart';
import CameraIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Camera';
import AddchartIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Addchart';
import PanoramaIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Panorama';
import Divider from '@mui/material/Divider';


const Item = ({ title, to, icon, isSelected, setSelected }) => {
    const theme = useTheme();
    const colors = tokens(theme.palette.mode);
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const { collapsed } = useProSidebar();
    const handleClick = () => {
        setSelected(title);
        if (typeof to === 'string') {
            // Handle internal routes
            navigate(to);
        } else if (typeof to === 'function') {
            // Handle external routes with callback function
            to();
        }
    };
    const textColor = isSelected
        ? colors.primary[500]
        : theme.palette.mode === 'dark'
            ? colors.grey[100]
            : colors.grey[200];
    const fontWeight = isSelected ? 'bold' : 'initial';
    return (
        <MenuItem
            onClick={handleClick}
            icon={icon}
            style={{
                background: isSelected ? colors.greenAccent[500] : "initial",
                color: textColor,
                borderRadius: "10px",
            }}
        >
            <Typography sx={{ fontWeight: `${fontWeight} !important`, fontFamily: 'Noto Sans' }}>{title}</Typography>
        </MenuItem>
    );
};

function Sidebartest() {
    const { toggleSidebar, collapseSidebar, broken, collapsed } = useProSidebar();
    const theme = useTheme();
    const colors = tokens(theme.palette.mode);
    const [selected, setSelected] = useState("");


    return (
        <Box
            sx={{
                "& .ps-menu-icon": {
                    justifyContent: "center",
                    display: 'flex',
                    flexDirection: 'column',
                    paddingLeft: "5px",

                },
                "& .pro-sidebar": {
                    borderRight: "none !important",


                },
                "& .ps-sidebar-container": {
                    /*background sidebar*/
                    background: `${colors.primary[400]} !important`,
                    display: 'flex',
                    flexDirection: 'column',
                    justifyContent: `${collapsed ? "center" : ""}`,
                    /*borderRadius: '20px'*/

                },
                "& .ps-menu-label": {
                    /*Text*/
                    padding: "1% !important",


                },
                "& .ps-menu-button:hover": {
                    /*changes text color when hover.*/
                    color: `${colors.primary[700]} !important`,
                    background: `${colors.grey[100]} !important`,
                    borderRadius: "10px",

                },
            }}
        >  {/*padding: '1rem' on the div makes it look interesting.*/}
            <div style={{ display: 'flex', height: '100%', padding: '1rem' }}>
                <Sidebar className="pro-sidebar" transitionDuration={-100}>
                    <Menu iconShape="square">
                        {!collapsed && (
                            <Box mb="25px">
                                <Box textAlign="center">
                                    <Typography
                                        variant="h2"
                                        color={colors.grey[100]}
                                        fontWeight="bold"
                                        sx={{ m: "10px 0 0 0" }}
                                    >
                                        CR
                                    </Typography>
                                    <Typography variant="h5" fontWeight="bold" color={colors.greenAccent[500]}>
                                        Management Tool
                                    </Typography>
                                </Box>
                            </Box>
                        )}

                        <Box padding={collapsed ? undefined : "1%"} margin={collapsed ? undefined : "10px"}>
                            <Item
                                title={collapsed ? "" : "Dashboard"}
                                to="/"
                                icon={<DashboardRoundedIcon />}
                                isSelected={selected === "Dashboard"}
                                setSelected={setSelected}


                            />
                            {!collapsed ? (
                                <Typography
                                    variant="h5"
                                    color={colors.grey[200]}
                                    fontWeight="bold"
                                    sx={{ m: "15px 0 5px 20px" }}
                                >
                                    Utilities
                                </Typography>
                            ) : <Divider />}
                            <Item
                                title={collapsed ? "" : "Trending"}

                                icon={<TwitterIcon />}
                                to={"/trending"}
                                isSelected={selected === "Trending"}
                                setSelected={setSelected}




                            />
                            <Item
                                title={collapsed ? "" : "HTE"}
                                to="/hte"
                                icon={<SportsSoccerIcon />}
                                isSelected={selected === "HTE"}
                                setSelected={setSelected}


                            />
                            <Item
                                title={collapsed ? "" : "Notification"}
                                to="/notification"
                                icon={<EditNotificationsIcon />}
                                isSelected={selected === "Notification"}
                                setSelected={setSelected}

                            />
                            <Item
                                title={collapsed ? "" : "Handover"}
                                to="/calendar"
                                icon={<PeopleIcon />}
                                isSelected={selected === "Handover"}
                                setSelected={setSelected}

                            />
                            <Item
                                title={collapsed ? "" : "Coverage"}
                                to="/calendar"
                                icon={<CalendarMonthIcon />}
                                isSelected={selected === "Coverage"}
                                setSelected={setSelected}

                            />

                            {!collapsed ? (
                                <Typography
                                    variant="h5"
                                    color={colors.grey[200]}
                                    fontWeight="bold"
                                    sx={{ m: "15px 0 5px 20px" }}
                                >
                                    Tools
                                </Typography>
                            ) : <Divider />}
                            <Item
                                title={collapsed ? "" : "NPAW"}
                                to="/calendar"
                                icon={<TimelineIcon />}
                                setSelected={setSelected}

                            />
                            <Item
                                title={collapsed ? "" : "CloudWacth"}
                                to="/team"
                                icon={<TimelineIcon />}
                                setSelected={setSelected}

                            />
                            <Item
                                title={collapsed ? "" : "Grafana"}
                                to="/tesm"
                                icon={<BarChartIcon />}
                                setSelected={setSelected}

                            />
                            <Item
                                title={collapsed ? "" : "Graf"}
                                to="/team"
                                icon={<CameraIcon />}
                                setSelected={setSelected}

                            />
                            <Item
                                title={collapsed ? "" : "Orion"}
                                to="/team"
                                icon={<BarChartIcon />}
                                setSelected={setSelected}

                            />


                            {!collapsed ? (
                                <Typography
                                    variant="h5"
                                    color={colors.grey[200]}
                                    fontWeight="bold"
                                    sx={{ m: "15px 0 5px 20px" }}
                                >
                                    Documents
                                </Typography>
                            ) : <Divider />}
                            <Item
                                title={collapsed ? "" : "Confluence"}
                                to="/team"
                                icon={<AddchartIcon />}
                                setSelected={setSelected}

                            />
                            <Item
                                title={collapsed ? "" : "Workplace"}
                                to={() => window.open('https://workplace.com', '_blank')}
                                icon={<AddchartIcon />}
                                setSelected={setSelected}

                            />
                        </Box>
                    </Menu>
                </Sidebar>
            </div>
        </Box >
    );
}

export default Sidebartest;
```